# Creating new column with length of another column with DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing average user ratings, languages, size and the amount of user ratings. Now I'd like to create a new column with the the amount of langauges.

Printing the languages returns:

```py
print(df.iloc[0]['Languages'])
#DA, NL, EN, FI, FR, DE, IT, JA, KO, NB, PL, PT, RU, ZH, ES, SV, ZH
```

Then create a new column 'Languages Count'

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Languages Count'] = len(row['Languages'].split(','))
```

Now looking at `Languages Count` they all are `1`. Now I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work. I was expecting the amount of languages for each row. So for the first one `13`. The second one only has 2 languages so I'd expect `2`

Comment: You assigned a single value (the length of the df) to a column. pandas just puts that value in all the rows...

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is the output you want? Doesn't each row have a single language?

Comment: @SiP I've changed the question to be more clear as well as the code that I've changed.

Comment: What is `print(df['Languages'].head(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: `['EN', 'EN', 'EN']`. There's way more languages in it however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count `comma`s with add `1` for count number of values:

```
df['Languages Count'] = df['Languages'].str.count(',').add(1)
```

Comment: So instead of creating a list from is and then taking it's length. You simply count all the komma's in the string and then add 1 since the last one in the string doesn't have one? Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Languages Count'] = df['Languages'].str.split(',').apply(len)
```